# Toggle form element based on text string in value?

Tags: jquery

The example below works: if `value` is `1` and is `checked` show `id="ethnic_other"`

Toggle script

```
$('input[name="ethnic_group"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#ethnic_other').toggle(+this.value === 1 && this.checked);
 }).change();
```

HTML (Shortened example - there are 18 radio buttons in the form)

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form__row">
        <label class="form__label">Please tick the box that best describes your ethnic group (2011 census definitions):</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group1" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - White British"><label for="form1_ethnic_group1">White - White British</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group2" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - White Irish"><label for="form1_ethnic_group2">White - White Irish</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group3" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller"><label for="form1_ethnic_group3">White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller</label>
        <!-- Note: Value is set to 1 -->        
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group4" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="1"><label for="form1_ethnic_group4">White - White Other*</label>        
    </div>   
    <div class="form__row" id="ethnic_other">
        <label class="form__label" for="form1_ethnic_group_feedback">* If other please specify</label><input id="form1_ethnic_group_feedback" name="ethnic_group_feedback" class="form__input" title="Ethnic group feedback" type="text">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

However, I'd like to keep the `value` the same as the `label`, every `other` radio button contains a `*` in the `value`. Can this be used instead of a number 1?

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form__row">
        <label class="form__label">Please tick the box that best describes your ethnic group (2011 census definitions):</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group1" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - White British"><label for="form1_ethnic_group1">White - White British</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group2" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - White Irish"><label for="form1_ethnic_group2">White - White Irish</label>
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group3" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller"><label for="form1_ethnic_group3">White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller</label>
        <!-- Note: Value is the same as label, contains a * --> 
        <input id="form1_ethnic_group4" name="ethnic_group" type="radio" value="White - White Other*"><label for="form1_ethnic_group4">White - White Other*</label>        
    </div>   
    <div class="form__row" id="ethnic_other">
        <label class="form__label" for="form1_ethnic_group_feedback">* If other please specify</label><input id="form1_ethnic_group_feedback" name="ethnic_group_feedback" class="form__input" title="Ethnic group feedback" type="text">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've changed the toggle script to this (see below), it half works. The `#ethnic_other` is hidden, so the script is working to a point. But when I click any radio button with a `*` as part of it's value string it doesn't toggle `#ethnic_other` visible?

```
$('input[name="ethnic_group"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#ethnic_other').toggle(+this.value === '*' && this.checked);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1. When you set `+` before value, then you convert the value to type number. But `*` is a string.
2. Value in you input is 'White - White Other*', not just '*'

So, you code should be like this:

```
$('input[name="ethnic_group"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#ethnic_other').toggle(this.value.indexOf('*') === this.value.length-1 && this.checked);
}).change();
```